# Method working only with < than 5000 args parameters

Tags: java, parsing, double, args

I have a small problem with a method to convert a string like "n.n+, n.n+, n.n+, ..., n.n+ ." in a sequence of double.
Everything works perfectly fine if I have lesse then 4998 values. If I have 4998 or more, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.178293466734042,"
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)
        at java.base/java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:506)
```

Here is the method I have written:

```
private static void parseDoubleArrayFromInput (String[] input, double[] parsedDoubles){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length - 1; i++){                     //Removes the last character, which is the comma, apart from the last valid string.
            if(i == input.length - 2)                                   //Does not consider the last string of the array since it contains only the dot.
                parsedDoubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(input[i]);        //Then, it fills the array of doubles with the parsed double.
            else
                parsedDoubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(input[i].substring(0,input[i].length()-1));
        }
    }
```

This is the class that generates the files

```
import java.time.*;

public class PRNG {

    public PRNG(){

    }

    public static String generatePseudoRandomNumbers(double actual, int repetitions) {        //main function, generates pseudo random numbers and
        String output = "";
        double[] values = new double[repetitions];
        for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
            double nextNumber = Math.pow(7,5)* actual % (Math.pow(2,31)- 1);    //algorithm to generate next pseudo random number
            actual = nextNumber;
            double singleResult = (2*(actual / (Math.pow(2,31) - 2))); //equation to shrink random numbers in a little range (0..100 in this case)
            output = output + singleResult + ", ";
        }
        output = output.substring(0, output.length()-3) + " .";
        return output;
    }

    public static int generatePseudoRandomNumbersTimes(double actual) {
        double nextNumber = Math.pow(7,5)* actual % (Math.pow(2,31)- 1);
        int singleResult = (int)(21*(nextNumber / (Math.pow(2,31) - 2)));
        return singleResult;
    }
}
```

And this is the class that should receive the input and parse it in a sequence of doubles

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StupidAlg {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        double[] doubleInput;
        if (args.length ==0) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        else {
            doubleInput = new double[args.length - 1];
            parseDoubleArrayFromInput(args, doubleInput);
            double target = sum(doubleInput) / 2;                   //find target value
            double value = findWeightedMedian(doubleInput, target);
            System.out.print(value);
        }
    }

    private static void parseDoubleArrayFromInput (String[] input, double[] parsedDoubles){
        // process all of the input
        for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
            // remove from the input things that will break the parsing
            // NOTE: other approaches could be used to ensure there is
            //   only a single ".".
            // NOTE: assumes the input to be US standard, as other approachs
            //        might use a "," for separator
            String clean = input[i].replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");

            // put the result
            parsedDoubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(clean);
        }
    }

    private static double findWeightedMedian (double[] input, double target){
        Arrays.sort(input);
        double sum = 0;
        double result = 0;
        for(double v : input){
            sum += v;
            if (sum >= target) {
                result = v;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static double sum (double[] input){
        double result = 0;
        for(double v : input){
            result = result + v;     //sum all values in array
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I used the library Arrays just because I didn't want to implement the sorting algorithm since it's an easy problem and this is the test file.

The input files are made this way

```
0.2931308777007562, 0.650659222761783, 1.6295518657467811, 1.8781948535500046, 0.8208889158637159, 0.680002497211101, 0.8019653053972547, 0.6308815354768946, 1.2259618232268485, 0.7403533791567696, 1.1192376940690332, 1.0279154591522324, 0.1751139268047306, 1.139766437131694, 0.05449995217332612, 1.9806957514776808, 1.5534795844494176, 1.3313636838750575, 0.22942446845530018, 1.937039533571377, 1.8234255749950423, 0.31362467102112684, 1.08984339804374, 0.9979823920856997, 1.090055974284239, 0.570751264291583 .
```

Comment: Your string has a comma in it `"1.178293466734042,"`

Comment: Yes, it's the one that the method should remove. And in fact it works with all the input that has less than 4998 values

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: It seems that you somehow split the input string. Could you please show us how you split it?

Comment: This is the minimum code, String[] input is simply args passed as it is, and double[] parsedDoubles is an empty array with length 1 less the one of args (this because the last string is the dot, that I don't want to have).

Comment: Do you get the same results if you re-order the strings in input[]?

Comment: Please provide an example with a String and the algorithm which creates the String array. So everyone can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, as soon as I’ll get home I’ll paste the code and the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear -- the `Double.parseDouble()` (actually, all of the `Integer`/`Long`/etc. `.parseXXX()` methods) will throw if the input String is not in the expected format.

So, it is best to:

- Catch the exception, or know that it can propagate
- Check the validity of the input before attempting to parse

The current algorithm assumes the location of the bad value. This approach seems very fragile. I would clean the input, and allow the exception to propagate.

```
private static void parseDoubleArrayFromInput (String[] input, double[] parsedDoubles){
    // process all of the input
    for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length; i++) {
        // remove from the input things that will break the parsing
        // NOTE: other approaches could be used to ensure there is 
        //   only a single ".".
        // NOTE: assumes the input to be US standard, as other approachs
        //        might use a "," for separator
        String clean = input[i].replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");

        // put the result
        parsedDoubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(clean);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it's fragile, but I've done it this way because I create the txt files with the values inside, and they are all made in the same way. The problem here is not that the code doesn't work, but that it doesn't work only with more than 4998 values. If, for example, I take the last values (with the one that threw the exception), as long as they are less than 4998 the program works perfectly

Comment: This works out, thank you very much. I still don't understand why the substring method did now work with more than 4998 values though

Comment: It's not the number of values, it's the value at that position.

Comment: And why it worked If I put that value in a smaller string? Sorry to be so noob

Comment: @M.Ianniello, as to the specifics of your algo, I think you have the check reversed. It should be `if (i != input.length - 2)`, as you want the normal case to parse without trying to take the substring, but the other case to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Array uses int internally so Integer.MAX_VALUE should be allowed but it also depends on datatype that you are storing in to Array and size of it and size of memory available for heap. Might not be the answer you were looking for but worth give it a try. you can find details [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-array-in-Java)

Comment: That would result in an OutOfMemoryError - *not* a NumberFormatException.